# Expression must have same datatype error while executing a query

Tags: sql, oracle

Need your help in resolving the error which I'm getting. I'm using a union to join two queries and is giving me an error. Below is the query along with the error message.

### Query:

```
SELECT 'Firewall Rules' as Platform
       , 'TestCount' TestCount
       , 'TestPassCount' TestPassCount
       , percentage as percentage
       , firewall_name as Server 
from(
    SELECT round(avg(replace(PER_OF_VIOLATING_RULES, '%', ''))* 1 , 2)||'%'  as percentage
           , firewall_name
    from table1 
    group by firewall_name
)
union
select 'Database' as Platform
       , count( *) TestCount
       , count(case when result_status = 'Not A Finding' then 1 end) TestPassCount
       , Round(  count(case when result_status = 'Not A Finding' then 1 end) / count(*) * 100 , 2) percentage
       , asset as Server
FROM table2 
group by asset
```

### Error message:

```
ORA-01790: expression must have the same datatype as corresponding expression
01790. 00000 -  "expression must have the same datatype as the corresponding expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 37
```

Can someone help in modifying the query?

Comment: Your 1st query block is treating `percentage` as a string whereas the 2nd query block is numeric.  In addition, you have a lot of implicit casting going on which could cause problems as well.

Comment: On a side note: Don't store numbers as strings. So rather than storing PER_OF_VIOLATING_RULES as '99.123%' (or '99,123%' depending on the format you decided on) store the unambiguous number 99.1234. As is, you rely on session settings matching the decimal separator in the string in your query, which you shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

With set operations the projection of all the subqueries must have the same signature. So the datatypes of the columns must match.

With your top subquery you are returning string literals for `TestCount` and `TestPassCount` but numbers for the bottom subquery. So you need to change one of those projections. You could use `to_char()` to cast the numerics to strings but it would be better to remove the string literals in the firewall subquery:

```
SELECT 'Firewall Rules' as Platform
       , to_number(null) TestCount
       , to_number(null) TestPassCount
       , percentage as percentage
....
```

Alternatively you could use literal zeroes, it depends on your needs.

---

By the way: you can use UNION ALL rather than UNION, because the result set of both subqueries is guaranteed to be a set due to the `platform` literal. UNION does a sort to ensure uniqueness, so for a big query UNION ALL is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`'TestCount' TestCount` and `TestPassCount' TestPassCount` are string in first query and you are fetching numeric values in second query for the respective fields.

You can `typecast` using `TO_CHAR` Function in the second query to overcome this.